# Table View Cell in external nib. Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios

So I have been building a table view in storyboard and I created an external Nib file with my custom UITableViewCell. Everything is working great. However, there is a button on the table view cell that I would like to have connected to a view in the storyboard, via a segue. Now I'm still very new to all this, so how would I connect the button on the custom cell to the view controller in the storyboard? Have I gone about this completely wrong? If so, how would I restructure my project quickly and easily? I would be grateful if you could provide a little explanation so I can learn from this.

Thanks for any help,
Regards,
Mike

Comment: i guess you cannot do this within the storyboard. you need access the button from code and setup the action on your own.

Comment: Ok, and roughly, how would I go about doing that? Also, I just had quick thought. What if I build the cell in its own little space in the storyboard. Would that work?

Comment: Ok, that idea I had really doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set a button inside UITableViewCell in storyboard using story board. I have done similar thing before. So, here's a solution;

- Create prototyoe cell inside UITableView cell and add a UIButton to it.
- Create a segue from  the button to a new view controller and then choose the modal or push.

Now, in the UITableViewData datasource cellForRowAtIndexPath;

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    UIButton *button = ((UIButton*)[cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0])
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello Text"
    ;
    return cell;
}
```

Now, when your button is clicked your prepareForSegue: is called.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier"]){
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
        NewViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
       if(button.tag == 1)
          viewController.someobject = ...
       else 
          viewController.somobject = ...
    }
}
```

And that should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've marked you up for the very detailed solution. I'll try it tomorrow morning (I hate working on problems in the evening) and when I get it to work, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks again for the great response.

Comment: I'm struggling to implement this code, and have been for a little while. Could you perhaps explain the steps I should take, from scratch? Regards, Mike.

Comment: Hey, but could you make it work or should I elaborate it more ?

Comment: I'm very close to making it work. I've set up the segue (and it works with a test button in the actual view controller), I'm just trying to make a way for the TableViewCell UIButton to call performSegueWithIdentifier. I was thinking of a notification to do so, because I can't really see how your code works. Sorry I'm so useless,  I'm not always able to get my head around what people suggest, and see the what they're trying to do.

Comment: Well, it is just a matter of practise and interest. The more you do, the more expert you become, keep on doing things and never loose your interest, you will surely become good at it.

Comment: Thank you very much insane. I'm gradually getting there. I get things done, maybe not in the most efficient way, but they do get completed with time and effort. I do find it hard however, having taught myself what I know in my spare time around work hours, but thankfully the fantastic community here is always willing to help and always do a great job of explaining things. I'm learning more and more each day thanks to people like you. As for this problem, the objective has been completed and I'm trudging on until I hit the next one. Thanks again. Regards, Mike.